# button href won't redirect

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm really confused since yesterday I've wrote a Delete button that deletes all the loaded rows from the database and yesterday it worked just fine while today it is not working and I can't find the reason.

Code:

```
<button type="button" class="butDel"  onClick="javascript: return confirm('Are you sure?');" href="index.php?startID=<?php echo $firstID; ?>&endID=<?php echo $lastID; ?>">Delete</button>
```

So I tried to delete each part of the code to see why it doesn't work but it's not working even when I got the JS onClik part off. It is not working when I'm deleting the PHP part and it's not even working when I fill `href` with `http://www.google.com`.
The problem is it just won't redirect the browser to the location of href.
Tried from a localhost and a live server.

I'm out of ideas.

Comment: We need more than that 1 snippet to try and help. Any more code you can share?

Comment: @James I'm saying that the button isn't redirecting no matter what's going on inside. What kind of additional code would help you understand the issue?

Comment: Buttons do not have href, so not sure how it worked.

Comment: @epascarello, really? I can swear it worked mate.

Comment: Do you see href listed in the attributes? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button Unless you changed it from an anchor to a button, it should have not have worked.

Comment: @epascarello, that's exactly what I did lol. Any suggestions on how to make a button with a confirm that will redirect upon confirmation then?

Comment: Like above comments, buttons don't have href attribute. The JS might not execute if you're inside a block of php code and you have an error. Check your code for errors in php.

Comment: It all works with an anchor tag. No way to get the same result with a button?

Comment: Either style the anchor to look like a button or add JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an assignment to `window.location` in the `onclick` attribute. You can use an `if` statement to make it depend on the confirmation.

```html
<button type="button" class="butDel"  onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) window.location.href='index.php?startID=<?php echo $firstID; ?>&endID=<?php echo $lastID; ?>';">Delete</button>
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I wanted but it shows no confirm popup.

Comment: Sorry, there was a missing `)`

Comment: Didn't you see the syntax error in the Javascript console?

Comment: I've moved from Sublime to Brackets and still didn't get used to it. JS console? You mean the console in Chrome Dev tools? Thank you for the help mate.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 <button type="button" class="butDel"  onClick="javascript: if(confirm('Are you sure?'))" window.location.href="index.php?startID=<?php echo $firstID; ?>&endID=<?php echo $lastID; ?>">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Really, I've triple checked that I'm editing the same file the I access and it is the correct file. Have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: The `return` statement will prevent the next statement from executing.

Answer (score 0):

Make an anchor tag for the href, buttons don't support the href attribute.